# How to conditionally change values in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, nan

I am trying to do some basic data analysis from a dataframe that was concatenated using three other dataframes. As you can imagine there are NaN values in some of the dataframe columns after the merging. All the individual dataframes contain most of the same headings but are from three separate years (2017,2018,2019)

My data of interest concerns 2 columns:

1. a column with the names of coutries around the world ('COUNTRY")
2. a column called "REGION" (which describes the geographical location a country is located in ex. "Sub-Sarahan Africa", "Latin America" etc).

Since the country and region column don't  change (i.e they must always correspond), I thought there might be a way to change the NaN values in the rows of df.REGION column to match the corresponding country in their respective row. I wish to make this a permanent alteration to the df.

I've attempted using dataframe mapping but could not succeed there. So I attempted a dictionary and for loop method (which seems to also be the wrong way to go about it). But this is the code I tried below. Spoiler....it didn't work.

```
dictionary = {'Belize':'Latin America and Caribbean',
              'Namibia':'Sub-Saharan Africa', 
              'Puerto Rico':'Latin America and Caribbean',
              'Somalia':'Sub-Saharan Africa', 
              'Somaliland Region':"Sub-Saharan Africa",
               'South Sudan':'Sub-Saharan Africa'}

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    country = df.COUNTRY
    region = df.REGION
    for key in dictionary:
        if country in dictionary:
            df.REGION = dictionary[d]
```

The dictionary above has the country name as keys and the regions as values.

Does anyone know of a way to use some sort of mapping function to fill the missing (NaN) values (i.e region names) in the REGION column that corresponds to the country names in the dictionary above?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` function and replace all values where REGION is None:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"COUNTRY": ["Germany", "USA", "Belize"],
               "REGION": ["Europe", "North America", None]})

df.loc[df.REGION.isnull(), "REGION"] = df.loc[df.REGION.isnull()].COUNTRY.map(dictionary)
```

Comment: very cool use of the map function. I will for sure add this to my techniques. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Namibia', 'Belize']})

df['Region'] = df.Country.replace(dictionary)
```

Result:

```
   Country                       Region
0  Namibia           Sub-Saharan Africa
1   Belize  Latin America and Caribbean
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. Very simplistic solution.